# nnimap-finish-retrieve-group-infos: End of file during parsing

Tags: gnus, error

I read my mails with gnus (emacs master 30.0.50/windows11/mingw64), it used to work very well but suddenly, I now run into the following error :

`nnimap-finish-retrieve-group-infos: End of file during parsing`

I removed all gnus temporary files (`rm -rf ~/.gnus.d`) and reinitiated all accounts.

I restarted gnus with no other packages loaded. Here is what I get :

```
Initializing the registry
Reading Gnus registry from ~/.gnus.d/.gnus.registry.eieio...
Remaking the Gnus registry
Opening nntp server on gmane...done
Opening nntp server on gnus...done
Opening nnimap server on gmail...
Opening connection to imap.gmail.com via tls...
Opening connection to imap.gmail.com...done
Opening nnimap server on gmail...done
Subscribe newsgroup: nnimap+gmail:Archive
Subscribe newsgroup: nnimap+gmail:Brouillons
Subscribe newsgroup: nnimap+gmail:INBOX
Subscribe newsgroup: nnimap+gmail:Pourriel
Subscribe newsgroup: nnimap+gmail:[Gmail]/Corbeille
Subscribe newsgroup: nnimap+gmail:[Gmail]/Messages envoyés
XX new newsgroups have arrived
Checking new news...
Reading active file via nnnil...done
Reading active file from gmane via nntp...
Opening nntp server on gmane...done
Reading active file from gnus via nntp...
Opening nntp server on gnus...done
nnimap gmail splitting mail...
nnimap read 0k from imap.gmail.com
nnimap gmail splitting mail...done
nnimap read 1k from imap.gmail.com (initial sync of 8 groups; please wait)
nnimap read 262k from imap.gmail.com (initial sync of 8 groups; please wait)
nnimap-finish-retrieve-group-infos: End of file during parsing
```

Even with a clean install I still get this error.

Then, the `*Group*` buffer remains empty and gnus is unresponsive.

I made no modification to my gnus settings. Usually, `end of file during parsing` means there is a missing parenthesis somewhere but this would cause an error much earlier in the gnus process.

What file is being read that makes a parsing error ?

Comment: I tried with another computer with older but similar configuration (emacs 29.0.50/windows 10/mingw64). I run into the exact same error although I did not modify gnus configuration. The error may be then not related to gnus/emacs itself.

Comment: To start the journey of debugging, it may be helpful to find the file containing the function or variable indicated in the error message.  That would be done by using `M-x find-function` or `M-x find-variable`.  I also found it with a Google search by typing double quotes around the name `nnimap-finish-retrieve-group-infos` and came up with the file on Github:  https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/gnus/nnimap.el#L1542  I have no idea whatsoever what `deffoo` is ... maybe a typo?

Comment: Thanks for your help, `deffoo` is a macro, much like `defun` as stated [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Writing-New-Back-Ends.html). I tested `wanderlust` on the same computer. It works out of the box. So the problem seems related to `gnus` only.